# Core Bluetooth CBCentralManager always reports state as Unknown on ipad2

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth, ipad-2

I am working with corebluetooth to connect with bluetooth printer, but I have a problem with ipad2. When I scan device, CBCentralManager always call to centralManagerDidUpdateState with state unsupported and cannot call another delegate method.

Comment: iPad 2 don't have a Bluetooth Low-Energy Chip, that's why. The first iPad to have it is iPad 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue today.

CoreBluetooth works with BLE and Bluetooth 4.0. The iPad 2 does not support BLE, therefore you get an unknown state.